# Invoke-Sqlcmd fail when connecting to Postgresql Database and doing SQL command

Tags: postgresql, powershell

I have been able to connect to the PostgreSQL Server with OdbcConnection.

```
$DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL ANSI(x64)};Server=$MyServer;Port=$MyPort;Database=$MyDB;Uid=$MyUid;Pwd=$MyPass;"
$DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection;
$DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString;
$DBConn.Open();
```

However I wish to connect to the PostgreSQL with command Invoke-Sqkcmd. I was told to always try to use the cmdlets and their commands. I tried it with:

```
$MyPort = '5432'
$MyUid = 'postgres'
$MyPass = 'pass'
$DBSvr = 'server'
$DBase = 'database'
$sqlcmd = 'SELECT email_addr FROM member_subscribers LIMIT 20'
$data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sqlcmd -Database $DBase -ServerInstance    $DBSvr$MyPort -Username $MyUid -Password $MyPass 
Write-Output $data
```

However, I get the error.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to 
SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and 
that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - 
Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
At line:13 char:9
 + $data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sqlcmd -Database $DBase -ServerInstance    ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd],   SqlException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

 Invoke-Sqlcmd : 
 At line:13 char:9
 + $data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -query $sqlcmd -Database $DBase -ServerInstance ...
 +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd],  ParserException
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScri 
ptCommand
```

I know the credentials should be correct. So maybe the formatting is just wrong? I am not sure....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke-SQLCmd is a SQL Server cmdlet.  You can't connect to postgres using it.

Comment: I am guessing there is no cmdlet that can connect to postgres?

Comment: There isn't a native one, but I've written a "framework" that works for any ADO.NET provider.  https://github.com/MikeShepard/POSH_Ado.  I haven't written a submodule for Postgres, but it should be pretty simple.